# Is node-gyp Visual Studio requirements

Tags: node.js, windows, node-gyp

Is node-gyp requires VS on Windows after building app for distribution, or this requirement only for development?

Comment: node-gyp is a build tool so is a requirement when building

Comment: so if I build my app that uses node-gyp on Ubuntu, it will work ok on Windows without any requirements?

Comment: No, that is not the case.  node-gyp compiles native C code.  So, if you compile on one architecture it won't necessarily work on another.  So OSX -> Ubuntu -> Windows is not always compatible.

Comment: Running inside a container (like Docker) can help here.  Because you can build *inside* the container and target the prod architecture.  Good luck!